# I can't create Link Server to MySQL in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to access data stored on MySQL from SQL Server. 
I have followed the instructions on this site
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx

I created the linked server with no problems but when I tried to select data using OPENQUERY I get the following Error

```
Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot process the object "
SELECT
CAST(t.name AS CHAR) AS team_name,
CAST(TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(su.first_name, " ", su.middle_name , " ", su.last_name), " ", " ")) AS CHAR) AS fullname,
CAST(su.login_user AS CHAR) AS username,
CAST(t.billing_department_id AS UNSIGNED) AS billing_dept_id
FROM my_table.users AS su
INNER JOIN my_table.teams AS t ON t.team_id = su.team_id
WHERE client_id = 1 ". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SQLSERVER_1" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQLSERVER_1, '
SELECT
CAST(t.name AS CHAR) AS team_name,
CAST(TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(su.first_name, " ", su.middle_name , " ", su.last_name), " ", " ")) AS CHAR) AS fullname,
CAST(su.login_user AS CHAR) AS username,
CAST(t.billing_department_id AS UNSIGNED) AS billing_dept_id
FROM my_table.users AS su
INNER JOIN my_table.teams AS t ON t.team_id = su.team_id
WHERE client_id = 1 ') AS su
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this, what can I do to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The solution is very silly but I can't belive it was the solution. The solution is to simple Remove the space between the MySQL select and the single quote. so it becomes 'SELECT CAST(t.name AS CHAR) AS team_name, ........

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but not until after we upgraded to the MySQL ODBC 5.3 driver.  Since we had a lot of existing queries with a new line I spent some time trying to find a fix.  Turns out the problem was caused by using the unicode version of the driver.  Once I switched to ANSI the problem went away.